# Java null layout results in a blank screen

Tags: java, swing, layout

When I try to use setLayout(null), I get a plain gray screen and none of my components are present. Do I need to give every component in ColorPanel an x, y value?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame GUI = new JFrame();
        GUI.setLayout(null);
        GUI.setTitle("Betrai");
        GUI.setSize(500, 500);
        GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(Color.white);
        Container pane = GUI.getContentPane();
        JButton continueButton = new JButton("TEST");
        continueButton.setBackground(Color.red);
        continueButton.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 40);
        pane.add(continueButton);
        GUI.setVisible(true);
        GUI.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        GUI.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Do I need to give every component in ColorPanel an x, y value?" Yes, and that is why you should be using layout managers. Let them to all the work so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the code and I can see your button, just like you specified!

You need to add the `ColorPanel` to the layout and set the bounds (just like you did for the test button).

```
    panel.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
    pane.add(panel);
```

*But you should not use `null` layout. There is almost always another layout that can fullfill your needs!*

Comment: +1 for not use null layout. Anyway there isn't a layout for all the needs, but if you need a custom layout, it's better to write your own LayoutManager then using a null one.

Comment: @0verbose: Correct, added *almost*.

Comment: @0verbose This layout is just for the title screen of a game, I'd rather just set up four buttons in null than write my own. And dacwe, that was exactly what I needed for the panel to show, but now the button is invisible. I made sure add the button after the panel.

Comment: @Bro mcBro: in limited situations you can use null layout with no problem.

Comment: @0verbose Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Do you know why the button wouldn't show up when the ColorPanel panel was added to the container?

Comment: @Bro mcBro: with a null layout maybe you have to set it to be visible explicitly.

Comment: @0verbose That compiled fine, but the button is still invisible.

Comment: Nevermind, I reversed the order in which I added the components to the container and the button works great now. Thanks for all the help, 0ver.

Answer (score 2):

When you use null for a layout manager, you are telling Swing that you want to do absolute positioning. The rules for absolute positioning is that you must set the bounds for each component you add to the Container before you add it.

Here is where you'll find Oracle's canonical example of using no layout manager.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Note also, you should be wrapping everything as follows:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ... GUI creation stuff here ...
    }
});
```